# implode and show with key - php

Tags: php

I have an array with just a single element. The key and value looks like this:

```
Array ( [test] => 12342 )
```

**Result i want is this inside an variable:**

```
test = '12342'
```

**I tried following:**

```
$test = "'" . implode(" ", $metric) . "'";
print_r($test);
```

But this gives only gives me: `'12342'`, i wanted the `'='` after key and `''` around the value (this is used for SQL later on). So the result should be `test = '12342'`. Does not look like implode would work here. I tried looking at `http_query_builder` but failed.

Comment: This is a bad approach for building dynamic queries. Read about __prepared statements__.

Comment: you want to build a string out of your array and then use it in your query? that's not a good idea imho. agree with @u_mulder: go for prepared statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this array is only ever going to contain one single item, then you don’t need to loop through the data, but you can use `key` and `current` instead:

```
$data = ['test' => 12342];
echo key($data) . " = '" . current($data) . "'";
```

[`key`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) gets you the key of the “current” item, and [`current`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) gets its value.

Comment: I didn't know that you could that, +1

Comment: Always one. Accepted Answer, thank you. Not needing loop +1

Answer (score 1):

By just replying your question as it is using that unique example you would do it this way assuming there is only 1 value inside your array :

```
$yourArray = array('test' => '12342');

foreach($yourArray as $key => $value) {

    $test = $key . " = '" . $value . "'";
}

print_r($test);
```

If there are multiple you would do this, as each key is unique :

```
$yourArray = array('test' => '12342', 'testing' => '24321');
$test = array();

foreach($yourArray as $key => $value) {

    $test[$key] = $key . " = '" . $value . "'";
}

var_dump($test);
```

Comment: If more than one $test is only the last one.

Comment: @AbraCadaver ineeded. I added another example if there are multiple values inside the array.